# Swift UIPickerView with UITapGestureRecognizer in SKScene?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, sprite-kit

I have added the UIPickerView to my SKScene with the following code:

```
let uiPicker = UIPickerView()
uiPicker.dataSource = self
uiPicker.delegate = self
view.addSubview(uiPicker)
```

(I have not included all the delegate methods here as they are all functioning correctly).

I then added a UITapGestureRecognizer like this:

```
let doSomething = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "doSomething")
doSomething.delegate = self
uiPicker.addGestureRecognizer(doSomething)
```

The problem is that the tap gesture recogniser is not working. No errors are being generated, it is just not running the action.

What am I doing wrong and how to get it working properly? What I want is to have UIPickerView in the scene but run an action when a user taps the current selected row. The action needs to be passed the row data.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

You probably forgot to set the delegate.

```
@interface GameScene() <UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>
```